# Printing a random value from a .csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, random

I am a teacher who is trying to create a program that will display students that are comfortable reading in class. They have filled out a form that populates a spreadsheet if they choose that they are comfortable.

I would like to randomly sort their names from the .csv, so that I get a single name each time I run the program. I keep getting an error that my file has no len().

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import csv
import random

with open('1st_period.csv', 'r') as student_csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(student_csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)
    #This skips over the first line in the .csv (first_name, last_name)

    for line in csv_reader:
        random.shuffle(csv_reader)
        print(line[0])
```

Here is my .csv file in same folder as the python file

```
first_name
Joshua
Jeremy
Mary
Martha
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Your error is due to function random.shuffle takes a sequence as an argument while you are passing an iterator.  Python sequences are:  lists, tuples, byte sequences, byte arrays, and range objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) instead of `random.shuffle`:

```py
import csv
import random

with open("1st_period.csv", "r") as student_csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(student_csv_file)
    # This skips over the first line in the .csv (first_name, last_name)
    next(csv_reader)
    print(random.choice([line[0] for line in csv_reader]))
```

Prints (for example):

```
Jeremy
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks Andrej. I am trying to figure out why it worked so I can learn. Random.choice takes one element from the list, but how did you convert the iterator into a sequence (see first comment above). Does the "for loop" accomplish this?

Comment: @JoshuaMitchell I used list-comprehension `[line[0] for line in csv_reader]` - this creates a list from the first (`[0]`) column from CSV file. Then `random.choice` picks one item at random from this list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```py
import csv
import random

with open("1st_period.csv", "r") as student_csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(student_csv_file)
    
    student_names = list(csv_reader)[1:]
    random.shuffle(student_names)

    for name in student_names:
        print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Did you convert the .csv to a list using the "list()" function? Is that what made it work? Any information is very helpful for me as a beginner.

Comment: @JoshuaMitchell That's right. Also the same line omits the csv header.